# Why are the CN payloads removed in apprtc ( google webRTC app )

Tags: html5-audio, audio-streaming, p2p, webrtc, noise

I was studying the code used in https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=01224719 and I have noticed one thing that I haven't understood. Why the CN ( comfort noise )constraints are removed from the SDP session when creating an offer?  Aren't they important to reduce the noise level in the connection?

The SDP descriptor is transformed as follows, I have posted only the relevant parts :

**Original:**

```
    ...
    m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 106 105 13 126 ( remove 106 104 2 )
    a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000 ( removed )
    a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000 ( removed )
    a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000   ( removed )
    ...
```

**Modified:**

```
    ...
    m=audio 1 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 126
    ...
```

In this case the protocol 111 ( opus/4800) will be used in both cases to encode the audio stream, so what  is the point to remove the lines regarding CN?

Comment: I noticed this too when setting the opus codec to stereo. The opus codec is indeed automatically used, but still [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402990/is-there-a-way-to-choose-codecs-in-webrtc-peerconnection) question does provide code to use opus and does remove the cn lines. I have no idea why as CN generates noise when there is no sound, and it is no audio codec (and thus won't be used over opus).